# Getting a value by type="hidden"

Tags: php, html, function

In my application I'm printing out searchresults. I want to use those searchresults to send an invite to become a member in that group. I'm printing out those userdata but I'm wondering how I can use those data into another function (sendInvite or something). I have to get the user_id of that people (`$row['user_id']` but I don't know how I can get it. I'm thinking about `type="hidden"` but I never used it before.)

PRINT OUT

```
   <div id="InviteGroupMembers">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?group_id=" .$group_id; ?>" method="post">
                <div >
                    <input type="text" name="btnSearch" placeholder="Add people to group"/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit"  name="">Add</button>
                </div>
                </form>

            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?group_id=" .$group_id; ?>" method="post">
                    <?php
                    if (is_object($searchresult))
                        while ($row = $searchresult -> fetch_array()) {
                            echo "<div><p class='searchresults'><img src='uploads/" . $row['avatar'] . " " . "' alt='' />" .  $row['surname'] . " " . $row['name'] . " " . "<input type='submit' name='btnAddMember'class='addFriendToGroup' value='' /><input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='" . $row['user_id'] . "'/></p></div>"; }         

                    ?>
                </form>


        </div>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST["btnSearch"])) {
    try {
        $searchinput = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['btnSearch']);
        $searchresult = $user -> Search($searchinput);
    } catch(exception $e) {
        $feedback = $e -> getMessage("no results");
    }
}

if (isset($_POST["btnAddMember"])) {
    try{
        $group_receiver_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
        var_dump($group_receiver_id);
    }
    catch(exception $e) {
        $feedback = $e -> getMessage("no results");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

input type hidden would work for you in this instance. The output below is based on it being within `php` code. Other wise you will need to use `php` tags within the `value` attribute.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="$row['user_id']"/>
```

Then you can just get the post variable on form submission

Comment: I updated my question, now I always get the id of the LAST user, no matter which one I choose...

Comment: you need separate forms.